# need to input data into a textbox in shiny

Tags: r, shiny, shiny-server

I am making a simple system in Shiny that consist in a textBox and a number of checkboxes below it. I want that the user enters his ID into the textBox and automatically the system generates a text file with the name of the file the same as the user ID. I mean if the user enters "1234Q" as his ID, then the system will generate a file named "1234Q". So far I have done the following:

```
#part of the ui.R file
library(shiny)
shinyUI(fluidPage(
  titlePanel(h2("Title")),
  ###textbox for entering person data
  textInput("text2", label = h3("Personal ID"), value = ""),
  verbatimTextOutput("textBoxvalue"),
  hr(),
    mainPanel(
    textOutput("text1"),
    #some checkboxes here
    actionButton("action", label = "Next")
    )
))
```

and my server.R is roughly the following:

```
sw=0
shinyServer(function(input, output, session) {
  output$textBoxvalue <- renderPrint({ input$text2 })
  observe({
      fileNameData<-renderText({ input$text2 })
      fileName<<-paste(fileNameData(),sep=".","txt")
  })
  if (sw==0){
    #some operations here
    cat(someData,file=fileName,append=TRUE,sep=",") #save data
```

The problem that I have is that after the user inputs his ID I got that data into the fileName variable, which I intend to use it for saving the data that I will obtain after the if(sw==0) part, but nothing happens. For what I see the program  bypasses the observe part and goes directly to evaluate the if(sw==0) part. I have tried by using isolate and no luck at all. What can I do to solve this?

Update:

I have done something like the following:

```
shinyServer(function(input, output, session) {
  ###data received from the textbox, we need to save a file with this name only once

  ####observe
  observe({
    fileNameData<-renderText({ input$text2 })
    #print(fileNameData())  
    fileName<<-paste(fileNameData(),sep=".","txt")
  })
isolate({   
  ###end of data received from the textbox
  if (sw==0){
```

which roughly works fine, but I am missing the first data to be enter this because my filename is empty.

PD. In summary I just need the value of the text that the user inputs into a textfield and with that create a file with the same name. That process should be made only once.

Comment: Shouldn't the if statement be in some reactive expression or in observe ?

Comment: no, all the other parts of my program are working just fine

Answer (score 1):

If you want to link the execution of `if(sw==0{...}` to `'input$text2`, then `isolate` is the way to go. You need to wrap the `if ..` in `isolate`, and have that inside an observer to trigger it. So this should work

```
observe({
   fileNameData<-renderText({ input$text2 })
   fileName<<-paste(fileNameData(),sep=".","txt")

   isolate ({
      if (sw==0){
           #some operations here
           cat(someData,file=fileName,append=TRUE,sep=",") #save data
       }
    })
 })
```

Now the `isolate()`  is inside of the observer and should only trigger when `input$text2` changes.

Comment: thanks @JohnPaul, but is there not other way around without using isolate? the problem is that all the time is waiting for the input text to change and I need to capture that change only once